# How to keep a geth node synchronised on a ubuntu machine?

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

The requirement is keep a geth node synchronised almost always for a DAPP . The geth node is running on a ubuntu machine. The command being used to expose the geth rpc server is

```
geth --testnet --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpc
```

I usually connect to the server using putty . But when I close the putty session , the geth process also gets killed .I need to avoid this. What is required is to keep the geth syncing continuously , so that any user who uses the DAPP can make a transaction anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to make sure you started the process in fast mode so the chain is always up to date. You can use geth's --fast command for quickest possible syncs.

Also, increase cache size to --cache=1024 instead of the default 128

To keep the process running after your putty logout, you can obviously try screen **or** use [tmux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session) which is a superior way of doing this.

Comment: I have already used tmux to achieve this successfully . Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up geth as a service - https://github.com/bas-vk/config/blob/master/geth-systemd-service.md

Create a file `geth.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ethereum go client

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=geth 2>%h/.ethereum/geth.log

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Enable service

```
$ systemctl --user enable geth.service
$ systemctl --user start geth.service
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35454)

Comment: Changed. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

When you close SSH session, all processes you've run, either in background or foreground, receive [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (SIGnal Hang UP).  Most applications, including `geth`, react to this signal by gracefully terminating themselves.

There are several ways how you may prevent your applications from terminating on SSH session close:

1. Prevent them from receiving SIGHUP via [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) utility: `nohup geth <your geth options here> &`.  Note this `&` at the end, it sends the process into background.
2. Run `geth` inside virtual [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) terminal that will stay alive after SSH session close.  To do so, run `screen` then run your `geth` inside, then press `Ctrl+A` then press 'D' to detach your SSH session from virtual screen.  Then close SSH session.

Though, if your want your `geth` not only to survive SSH session close, but also to automatically restart after system reboot, you need to configure it as a system service:

1. Create file `/etc/systemd/system/geth.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Go Ethereum (geth)

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=geth <your geth options here>

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

2. Execute command `systemctl daemon-reload` to load `geth` service
3. Execute command `systemctl enable geth.service` to enable `geth` service
4. Execute command `systemctl start geth.service` to start `geth` service

You will probably need superuser privileges to do all these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html). Set it up, start your node and detach (don't exit). When you log out from putty, your node should still be running

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to run as systemd:

Create geth.service file (/etc/systemd/system/geth.service):

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/geth.service
```

Paste the below

```
[Unit]
Description=Geth

[Service]
Type=simple
User={$USER}
Restart=always
RestartSec=12
ExecStart=/bin/geth --syncmode "full" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Replace {$USER} with username above. Use [useradd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) to create a newUser if required.

```
sudo useradd -d /home/newUser -m --uid 10000 newUser
```

Enable and start the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable geth.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

service geth status
sudo service geth start
```

Check the status:

```
service geth status
```

Attaching to geth instance:

```
geth attach
```

Stop and disable the service:

```
sudo service geth stop
sudo systemctl disable geth.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```